# numpy.sum() gives `TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'`

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

The following code generated an unexpected `TypeError`:

```
import scipy.sparse
import numpy

coomatrix = scipy.sparse.coo_matrix((100,100))
numpy.sum(coomatrix)
```

the result:

```
TypeError: sum() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'
```

`scipy` version 0.14.0, `numpy` version 1.9.0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `numpy.sum` doesn't know how to handle sparse matrices. The following works as expected:

```
coomatrix.sum()
```